# Reading XML Hexadecimal Code from sql server and Converting Into Xml Format In ReactJS Issue

Tags: javascript, xml

I am working on reading hexdecimal code from sql server and convert that hexadecimal code to XML format In ReactJS
For converting i am using this below code, it returning xml but in that returned xml with lot of symbols are there,

```
var hex = 'PEVycm9yPg0KWE1MIGRvY3VtZW50IG11c3QgaGF2ZSBhIHRvcCBsZXZlbCBlbGVtZW50Lg0KDQpMaW5lOiAwDQoNCjwvRXJyb3I+DQo='

hexaToString(hex) {
    var str = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < hex.length; i += 2) str += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hex.substr(i, 2), 16));
    return str;
  }
```

for above code i am getting below xml format with symbols

https://codebeautify.org/hex-string-converter

how to remove those symbols, why i am getting those symbols, how to overcome this issue.
Please can anyone help me.

Answer (score 0):

The string you are trying  to decode isn't in hexadecimal format, it's in [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

Most of the characters in your string `hex` aren't valid hexadecimal characters.  Somewhat unhelpfully, JavaScript doesn't report any errors attempting to parse invalid hex digits or create characters from the resulting nonsense:

```
console.log(parseInt("PE", 16));    // logs 'NaN'
String.fromCharCode(NaN);           // logs character with code 0
```

To decode the string from Base64, use the [`atob` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding).  `console.log(atob(hex));` logs the following:

```
<Error>
XML document must have a top level element.

Line: 0

</Error>
```

Your string `hex` contains an error message encoded in Base64.

The CodeBeautify tool you link to also has a Base64 decoder, which generates the same output.

Comment: Thanks i will try this one in my reactjs application..@@@Luke Woodward